# Cropping an image depending on the orientation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the Facebook API to pull in 6 photos from a Facebook page and displaying them within a div. I would like the containing div to be square regardless of the size of the photo, but I would like the cropping of the image to depend on the orientation of the photo.

For instance, if the picture was taken in portrait mode, I would like the width of the image in the div to be the same as the width of the div and scale the height proportionately(centering the image vertically within the div).

If the image was taken in landscape mode, I would like to scale the image so that the height equals the height of the div and the width is scaled proportionately(centered horizontally within the div).

I am assuming this is going to require some Javascript, any suggestions on the best way to solve for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something neat using the images as background images:

The CSS part would be:

```
.photo-square {
    background: no-repeat 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Now you can set the background image with Javascript:

```
<div class="photo-square" style="background-image: url(...);"></div>
```

Unfortunately, you're out of luck with IE8 and lower. Tell me if you need an alternative solution.

Comment: I think this solution will work. My target audience is 15-30 year olds so I'm gonna assume most of them wont be using IE8 :P Thanks for the suggestion!